# Ussing reCAPTCHA on HTML5 whit contact-form.php

Tags: php, html, contacts

I have a website Html5 and try adding the reCaptcha still sending messages without activating the reCaptcha and last night I received over 300 messages a boot.

Help me please how to add so that only sent when the button is activated reCaptcha.
Send sends works well but not activation reCaptcha.

To start ***contact.html*** within my template I have put this way:

```
<!-- Start formulario de contacto -->   
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <h2>Formulario de contacto</h2>
                            <form action="php/contact-form.php" id="contact-form">

                                <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="contact-alert-success">
                                    <strong>Mensaje enviado correctamente!</strong>  Muchas gracias, pronto nos pondremos en contacto con usted, normalmente nuestro tiempo de respuesta es inferior a 2 horas.
                                </div>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" id="contact-alert-error">
                                    <strong>Error!</strong> A sucedido un error si lo desea puede contactarnos directamente en XXXX@tize.XXXX
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Nombre <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text"
                                                value=""
                                                data-msg-required="Por favor introduzca su nombre"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="name" id="name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>eMail <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="email" 
                                                value=""
                                                data-msg-required="Por favor introduzca su eMail"
                                                data-msg-email="Por favor introduzca un eMail válido"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="email"
                                                id="email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Asunto <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="text" 
                                                value=""
                                                data-msg-required="Por favor introduzca el asunto"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="subject"
                                                id="subject">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Mensaje <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <textarea
                                                data-msg-required="Por favor introduzca su mensaje"
                                                rows="10"
                                                class="form-control"
                                                name="message"
                                                id="message"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                    
                      <!-- Start Google Recaptcha -->
                         <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc88P4SAAAAANiT-ZXILUo-ET4xQmbivHy7uHc8"></div><br>
                      <!-- End Google Recaptcha -->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Cargando...">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>  
                        </div>
                       <!-- End formulario de contacto -->
```

And in php form to send the messages have this post with ***contact-form.php*** :

```
    <?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Enter your email address
$to = 'XXXX@tize.XX';

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

if($to) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'Name',
            'val' => $_POST['name']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'Email address',
            'val' => $_POST['email']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'Message',
            'val' => $_POST['message']
        )
    );

    $message = "";

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }

    $headers = '';
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');
    } else{
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    }

    echo json_encode($arrResult);

} else {

    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    echo json_encode($arrResult);

}
?>
```

Picture of my form, If anyone wants to see my website please let me know and send you the link. Thank you very much.
sending without activating the reCaptcha http://goo.gl/oSLQG9

Comment: Where do you check the captcha code? You doesn't.

Comment: Hi Lolka, I do not understand what you mean, excuse me.
What I need is my form to send messages only when activated Captcha since Sending do not work.
Therefore the Captcha photo's as if does not work.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? As I see it comes from js.

Comment: Hello, I do not cause errors. The problem I have is that ship well everything works fine. But the Captcha not working does nothing. Thank you.